# Рассчет оптимального маршрута локальной сети предприятия

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Тема «*Разработка программного приложения по расчету оптимального маршрута локальной сети предприятия*».

Может быть кто либо слышал или видел что то подобное? Нужен хотя бы какой-то пример.

Comment: Возьмите алгоритм Дейкстры или любой другой.

Comment: сначала нужно понять что из себя представляет маршрут локальной сети предприятия